# How remove array items using data from other array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm looking for a way, how remove array items with compare of other array.

```
keys = ['201','300'];

obj[0]=['someval','somename','201'];
obj[1]=['someval','somename','241'];
obj[2]=['someval','somename','300'];
obj[3]=['someval','somename','230'];
```

Now, how can i have obj array with elements equal to keys array ?
I want to archive this:

```
obj[0]=['someval','somename','201'];
obj[1]=['someval','somename','300'];
```

Thank You for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check whether the 3rd item in the inner array is present in the keys array

```js
keys = ['201', '300'];

var obj = []
obj[0] = ['someval', 'somename', '201'];
obj[1] = ['someval', 'somename', '241'];
obj[2] = ['someval', 'somename', '300'];
obj[3] = ['someval', 'somename', '230'];

obj = obj.filter(function(item) {
  return keys.indexOf(item[2]) > -1
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: @user2610146 what do you mean by custom array.... which part of the array is custom

Comment: obj array may have more values, example:
obj[3] = ['someval', 'somename','testval' '230','other'];

Comment: do you know which index in the array to be checked

Comment: And what will happens, when obj will be array like obejct instead of array ?